# Как посчитать сколько раз встречается блок с классом после определенного класса?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть много блоков:

```
<div class="calendar">
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
</div>
```

Как посчитать кол-во блоков с тегами event которые идут только после блоков с классом selected? Именно сразу после.
В указанном примере должно вернуть число 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

См. [CSS - селекторы](https://webref.ru/css#selectors), в JS они часто помогают)

```js
let events = document.querySelectorAll('.selected + .event');

console.log( events.length );
```

```html
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
```

Если бы его не существовало...

```js
let selected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
let events = [];

selected.forEach(function(el){
  let next = el.nextElementSibling;
  if( next.classList.contains('event') ) {
    events.push( next );
  }
}); // И вариации через reduce / filter

console.log( events.length );

// let e = [...document.querySelectorAll('.event')];
// e = e.filter( ev => ev.previousElementSibling.classList.contains('selected') );
```

```html
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day selected"></div>
<div class="day event"></div>
<div class="day"></div>
```

P.s. Можно свободно "ходить" во всех направлениях по DOM через:

• nextElementSibling

• previousElementSibling

• parentNode

• children

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь и такой развернутый ответ! :)